# Use redux dispatch from public folder in React

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, redux-toolkit

I am working on a code that uses scripts within the **public** folder to instantiate certain parts of my React app. I've setup a Redux store on the **src** folder to maintain a state that performs a certain task. However, I would also like to change the store values from results received on the public-side scripts using dispatch. As I'm receiving errors (likely pertaining to usage outside src/error in importing and using Redux on plain JS file), how can this be accomplished? My script files seem to break when moving them to src and importing them in the public index.html page, so it's becoming a hassle sharing data to the main app component. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: I'm assuming that you're using something like create-react-app which uses the `src` folder for the react app and `public` for static assets. If you include additional javascript in index.html, this code shares the same global namespace at runtime in the browser. You can set a global variable or create a CustomEvent (combined with addEventListener) to share data between the react app and these other scripts. The whole setups sounds a bit messy though, I'd check if you really need to include scripts that are not under `src`. This typically only applies to third party stuff like tracking etc..

Comment: @timotgl Thank you for the feedback. Yes, the structure is messy because the app utilizes third party scripts. As I'm fairly new to React, how would I be able to pass the global variable from the public-side script to src (where my Redux state is being managed)? I'm receiving errors when trying to import anything outside of src but need to change Redux state based on the response of the 3rd party scripts outside. If there is an example you can link me to, that'd be great.

Comment: It's really as simple as declaring a `window._myGlobalVar`. You could assign a function that dispatches an action for example. And then call this function from the external script. Your scenario sounds more like reacting to events though, I'd look into CustomEvent and addEventListener. "Micro frontends" deal with the same issue, the need to communicate across different apps on the page. When you wrote "based on the response of the 3rd party scripts outside" what does this mean exactly?

Comment: Was doing a bit of digging and also came across the window global variable. The 3rd party script has it's own events that are triggered when users perform tasks like signing in, etc. Hence the need to capture these event changes and apply it my react components.